# Permanently reserve a URL for a custom HTML / PHP document via wordpress theme or plugin

Tags: urls

I want to set up a custom HTML/PHP document at the url `https://myexample.com/special-instructions`.  In the past, what I would do is go into the WordPress CMS and add a Page post type with the title `Special Instructions`.  Then in my `wp-content/themes/my-theme` folder, I'd make a new template php file.  Then I'll be able to select the new template php file from the right hand menu in the CMS like this (see the red rectangle).

[image]

My concern with this approach is that the humans who will be using WordPress are not technically literate and always deleting things by accident. If they accidentally delete the "Special Instructions" page, then the `https://myexample.com/special-instructions` url will show a `404 not found`.

Is there a way for me to **permanently route** the `/special-instructions` url to php script that's recognized by my `wp-content/themes/my-theme` or a `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin` so that I can update it via `git` or `github.com`?  That way there's no chance regular human users will accidentally delete the page, or I can use `git checkout HEAD .` to restore the page.